# Swift Firebase snapshot.allValues update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently following a course on Udemy that teaches how to create a chat application with Firebase. However, I finished this course a couple of weeks ago, and then suddenly came the Swift 3.0 update. I am now struggling to convert this line in to Swift 3 Firebase:

```
firebase.child("Recent").queryOrderedByChild("chatRoomID").queryEqualToValue(chatRoomID).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


        var createRecent = true

        if snapshot.exists() {
            for recent in snapshot.value!.allValues {
                if recent["userId"] as! String == userId {
                    createRecent = false
                }
            }
        }

        if createRecent {

            CreateRecentItem(userId, chatRoomID: chatRoomID, members: members, withUserUsername: withUserUsername, withUserUserId: withUseruserId)


        }

    }
```

And I tried to do this:

```
 firebase.child("Recent").queryOrdered(byChild: "chatRoomID").queryEqual(toValue: chatRoomID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

        var createRecent = true

        if snapshot.exists() {

            if let values = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

                for recent in values {
                    if recent["userId"] as! String == userId {

                    }
                }
            }

                //}

            }

        }

    }
```

But of course this returned an error. Any ideas on how I would solve this particular code-convert?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mention the errors and line of errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:-

```
firebase.child("Recent").queryOrdered(byChild: "chatRoomID").queryEqual(toValue: chatRoomID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

        var createRecent = true

        if snapshot.exists() {

            if let values = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

                for recent in values {
                    if let userId = recent.value["userId"] as? String{

                      }
                }
            }
        }

    })
```